# Trouble Importing TXT File in Access with custom Import Spec

Tags: vba, ms-access, import

I have a slew of files that I need exported into Access. I'm using the following code to import all .txt files within the folder in a table in Access. I needed to use a custom `Import Spec` due to the presence of colons in some of the files which Access kept trying to treat as time.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()


Dim fso As Object
Dim fld As Object
Dim fil As Object
Dim FldPath As String
Dim MyResult As String



Const DestTable As String = "Splits"

FldPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\yahoo\yahoo_splits"



Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fld = fso.GetFolder(FldPath)

With DoCmd
    .SetWarnings False

    For Each fil In fld.Files
        If UCase(Right(fil.Name, 3)) = "txt" Then

            MsgBox (fil.Path)
            DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "SPTImport", "Splits", fil.Path, False


            CurrentDb.Execute ("Update Splits Set MyNewField = '" & fil.Name & "' where MyNewField is null")

        End If

    Next
    .SetWarnings True
End With



Set fil = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

MsgBox "done"



End Sub
```

When I try to import the file, I get the error:

`The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Fox.spt.txt'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.`

What is odd is that I even added the message box prompt just before the import step so that I could verify that it is calling the right path before it gets to the code that errors out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to manually import one of the text files using the Ribbon feature and be sure to select your Import Spec in the *Advanced* button of the wizard. See if any errors emerge.

Comment: There must be some kind of special characters in the file which is throwing things off.  Open your file in Notepad++ and visually inspect it that way.  Notepad++ is great for 'seeing' things in the data that you may not see simply by viewing the file in .txt format.  Also, as mention above, import it manually and see what happens during the process.  That should give you some clues as to what is going on.

Comment: I opened the txt file with Dreamweaver and no unusual characters in the file

Comment: I found out that the additional ".spt" text added before the ".txt" file extension was causing the import error. Once I removed the additional periods resolved the error.